# Ugly whitespace with multicols

Tags: spacing, multicol

Why is there [ugly whitespace](http://latex.informatik.uni-halle.de/latex-online/temp/olatex_276604_UEamPq9V0JUu.pdf) in the first column? How do I remove it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{align*}
            a = b
        \end{align*}
        \begin{align*}
            a = b
        \end{align*}
        \begin{align*}
            a = b
        \end{align*}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since there's no alignment happening inside the equations, it's syntactically cleaner to use the `gather*` environment instead of the `align*` environment. Better yet, use the `equation*` environment as it uses less vertical spacing than either `align*` or `gather*`. Best, of course, use the solution provided by @MarkSEveritt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're trying to put three equations on a line, then multicol isn't necessary. For example,

```
\begin{align*}
    a&=b &a&=b &a&=b
\end{align*}
```

produces output that looks like what you want from your MWE, and works for multiple lines of equations like usual for align. If that doesn't answer your question, then the problem was indentation. The following fixes your code.

```
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \noindent
    \begin{align*}
        a = b
    \end{align*}
    \begin{align*}
        a = b
    \end{align*}
    \begin{align*}
        a = b
    \end{align*}
\end{multicols}
```

i.e. you needed the `\noindent` to avoid the indentation from a new paragraph.

Comment: Out of interest, which one did you use in the end?

Comment: Definitely `\noindent` -- my example was just to illustrate the problem, not the actual equation I was trying to type -- there was a whole page's worth of equations, divided up in 2-column chunks. :)

Comment: Cool. I had the feeling that the MWE really way minimal!